# How to make google voice search British?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

I'm talking to google "*search by voice*" with british accent and it's write it all wrong! what should I do to make it into British?
[image: that microphone ("search by voice")]

Comment: you are silent on whether Android or PC but this resource might be helpful - https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2940021?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Chey-google-settings-you-can-change